# Copy csv & json data from S3 to Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have data like below format from s3 bucket.

```
"2010-9","aws cloud","{"id":1,"name":"test"}"
"2010-9","aws cloud1","{"id":2,"name":"test2"}"
```

I want to copy data in database like below.

Table

```
year   | env        | desc
2010-9 | aws cloud  |{"id":1,"name":"test"}
2010-9 | aws cloud1 |{"id":2,"name":"test2"}
```

I have written this command but not working. Could you please help me?

```sql
copy table
from 's3://bucketname/manifest' credentials 'aws_access_key_id=xx;aws_secret_access_key=xxx'
delimiter ','
IGNOREHEADER 1
REMOVEQUOTES
IGNOREBLANKLINES
manifest;
```

Comment: Does the `desc` field really have quotes _outside_ and _inside_ the field? (`"{"id":1,"name":"test"}"`) If so, this cannot be parsed by Redshift since the inner quotes make it look like the field has ended. You would either need to produce the file in a different format, or do some pre-processing to the file before loading it into Redshift.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Are you receiving an error message?

Comment: yes. desc filed data splitting with comma like  "id":1. is there any attribute to add single colon ' ' for filed

Comment: There are too many quotes in your third field. It can't be parsed. You might be able to load all the fields "as-is" (including quotes) and then do some fancy SQL to extract the data into a different table. You'd need to use REGEX functions.

Comment: Can you provide me fancy query to split from single filed. i have tried myself but no luck SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(desc, ',', 1) c1,
             SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(desc, ',', 2), ',', -1) c2,
              SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(desc, ',', 3), ',', -1) c3
from Test

Comment: You could load all the fields _without_ `REMOVEQUOTES`. Then, you can copy the fields to another table, ignoring the first and last character of each input field. It would be something like: `SELECT SUBSTRING(field, 2, LEN(field)-2)`

Comment: i want to remove double quotes in between { }  like this "2010-9","aws cloud","{id:1,name:test}". please help me if it is possible with sql query.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there - you just need to escape the double quotes inside the 3rd field (desc).  Per the

```
If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote
       appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with
       another double quote.  For example: "aaa","b""bb","ccc"
```

This is per rfc-4180 - https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt

I've also loaded json into a text field in Redshift and then used the json functions to parse the field.  Works great.